# Develop Silverlight 4 application with SL5 runtime installed

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

We are developing an application for Silverlight 4 as target system. All development machines currently have SL5 runtime installed.
In the past this worked quite good. But now we stumbled over some issues. (For example: Bindings for Style Setters are supported in SL5 but not SL4. But if you put such a binding in your XAML the compiler doesn't complain and on the dev machines (with SL5 installed) it runs. But on the productive machines with SL4 you get a runtime error.... )

Is there a way to ensure, that all we do is SL4 compliant without deinstall SL5 and install SL4?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but our development environment was exactly like yours. We did not run into problems.  When you target system as SL4, even if you put SL5 tags, compiler should have complaint since it is compiling against the SL4 not against your default setting. We never had to uninstall SL5 in our development environment.

Comment: We only had this issue once. As mentioned above, we added something like `<Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding X}"/>` to our style definition which was compiled with no error but threw a runtime error when only SL4 was installed (since the bindings in style setters is only supported in SL5).

We don't see a chance to prevent such exotic errors but deinstalling SL5. Do you see an alternative?

Comment: ahh good point. We did not have these WPF style/SL5 property setting in our code. So I am sure I am not of much help, sorry.